# how to call a simple class method by clicking custom button

Tags: custom-button

i am trying to call my method by clicking a custom button, but i also have to pass the id of that record as a list. here is my class & method. Can anyone please help me out.

```
public class Close_Date_Updation
    {
        public static void crUpdated(List<Opportunity> op)
        {  
          if(op[0].Hidden_Checkbox__c == True){
          Map<Id, Opportunity> OppMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>(op);
          List <Opportunity> childRecord = [Select id,Revision_Date__c,Service_Start_Date__c,CloseDate,Master_Opportunity__c from Opportunity where  RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Child_Opportunity' And Master_Opportunity__c IN: op];  //I hope Master_Opportunity__c  is Opportunity lookup

          for(Opportunity rt : childRecord){ 

              opportunity opp = OppMap.get(rt.Master_Opportunity__c);  
                rt.Service_Start_Date__c = Date.valueOf(opp.Service_Start_Date__c).adddays(-1);
                rt.Revision_Date__c = Date.valueOf(opp.Revision_Date__c).adddays(-1);  
                rt.CloseDate = Date.valueOf(opp.CloseDate).adddays(-1);



           }

            upsert childRecord;
            }
       }

    }
```

Comment: Please read this blog :) http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/03/04/passing-parameters-with-a-commandbutton/

Comment: @Martin.Kona I believe the OP is about the custom button on the page but not about the command button on a vf page.

Comment: what does the custom button code look like (amend your post)?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a general process issue.  Here is what I would recommend
1) Define how you are identifying your Opportunities (custom controller, account standard controller)
2) Setup you VF page to us the appropriate controller with the related VF page
3) Setup you button to call the VF 'wrapper' page with an iframe section.
4) Setup a VF page that will be called in the iframe section of the 'Wrapper' page and pass the appropriate parameter that is either hard coded are used as a apex field reference.